# How can I find out if a given content can be found in IPFS?

Tags: ipfs, ipfs-cli

I want to see if a given string (`"hello"` in this case) is accessible via IPFS. I am trying this:

```
echo hello | ipfs add -nq | ipfs cat
```

I am getting this:

```
Error: lock /root/.ipfs/repo.lock: someone else has the lock
```

What's going on? Is there a global lock, or is IPFS just protecting itself from a race condition that could have happened if I hadn't specified the `-n` flag?

This seems to work:

```
HASH=`echo hithere | ipfs add -nq` &&  ipfs cat $HASH
```

However, I wonder whether there is a more idiomatic way. This must be a fairly standard thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

> What's going on?

Your daemon is not running, so both `ipfs add` and `ipfs cat` tries to start an offline daemon at the same time which doesn't work (only one daemon per IPFS_PATH can run).

You need to run `ipfs daemon` in the background first, so then the commands will just hit `ipfs daemon`'s API instead of starting their own daemon.

> This seems to work:
>
> ```
> HASH=`echo hithere | ipfs add -nq` &&  ipfs cat $HASH
> ```

Yes because you are using `&&` which schedule them to wait on each other first.